# load infile from txt file doesnt work

Tags: mysql, load, load-data-infile

I have problems with loading my data from a txt file into my table

Tables:

```
 CREATE TABLE s_schueler (
  s_schnr int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  s_name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  s_k_klasse varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  KEY s_k_klasse (s_schnr),
  CONSTRAINT s_schueler_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (s_k_klasse) REFERENCES k_klassen (k_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=39 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



CREATE TABLE `k_klassen` (
  `k_id` char(4) NOT NULL,
  `k_bez` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`k_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Query:

```
LOAD DATA
    INFILE 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/SQL-schueler2.txt'
    INTO TABLE s_schueler
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    (s_name,s_k_klasse);
```

Since i have my ID on Auto_INCREMENT i dont use it as a parameter

Text file:

```
Ruben 01VL
Sean 03TA
Paul 03TB
```

Error:

Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test`.`s_schueler`, CONSTRAINT `s_schueler_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`s_k_klasse`) REFERENCES `k_klassen` (`k_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Answer (score 0):

From the MySQL reference manual on LOAD DATA INFILE:

To ignore foreign key constraints during the load operation, issue a SET foreign_key_checks = 0 statement before executing LOAD DATA.